# How to Schedule Component using PHP in Drupal Rules

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, schedule, drupal-rules

I'm looking to "Schedule a Component" in Rules using some PHP. I'm able to set a value using "values known by the strtotime() function. Like +1 day.", but I would really like to use PHP to set the value (I'm wanting to set the scheduled date to a value in another field). I understand that there is a "PHP Evaluation" area when I switch to "Data Selection" mode, but am unable to write any PHP that will work with it.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Could you add the code you've tried? Maybe there's just a small tweak needed

Comment: Ok, here's what I got: http://pastebin.com/AWXKkPQE

Comment: Clive: I misread what you were asking for. I was just trying to use something generic like <?php echo "2001-03-10 17:16:18"; ?> to test it out.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP Evaluation for Scheduled Evaluation Date expects you to return a timestamp without PHP delimiters. For example:

```
return strtotime('2001-03-10 17:16:18');
```

Note that any time in the past will trigger the rule on the next cron run.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Will I be able to do something like $node->field;? I'm trying to use the value of another field to set the date of the scheduled event. I hope I'm explaining myself well enough. :>